# How to delete "px" from 245px

Tags: javascript, string, variables, erase

Whats a simple way to delete the last two characters of a string?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

To convert `245px` in 245 just run:

```
parseInt('245px', 10);
```

It retains only leading numbers and discards all the rest.

Comment: This is the most malleable way, but you should always specify the radix `parseInt('245px', 10)`

Comment: You're right: the (strange) default is octal when the string starts with '0'... How many times I got an error for `parseInt('09')`!

Comment: what do you do when value is like 35.5px..using parseInt would result in 35 only

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: you can use 'parseFloat' (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

Answer (score 43):

use

```
var size = parseInt('245px', 10);
```

where 10 is the **radix** defining `parseInt` is parsing to a **decimal** value

#### use parseInt but don't use parseInt without a [radix](http://books.google.nl/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=crockford+radix&source=bl&ots=HHuno9s6eI&sig=xJafqBlVTBvweoD5R0x35MErsTo&hl=nl&ei=MENFTYHjOMKEOrjbxLgB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

The signature is `parseInt(string, radix)`

The second argument forces parseInt to use a base ten numbering system.

- The default input type for ParseInt() is decimal (base 10).
- If the number begins in "0", it is assumed to be octal (base 8).
- If it begins in "0x", it is assumed to be hexadecimal

why? *if $(this).attr('num') would be "08" parsInt without a radix would become 0*

Answer (score 25):

To convert a pixel value without the "px" at the end. use parseFloat.

```
parseFloat('245px'); // returns 245
```

*Note: If you use parseInt, the value will be correct if the value is an integer. If the value is a decimal one like 245.50px, then the value will be rounded to 245.*

Comment: As my edit to make a precision was rejected, I'm gonna put this in comment, `parseFloat()` does not take radix like `parseInt()` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555649/second-argument-to-parsefloat-in-javascript#answer-8555676)

Answer (score 17):

This does exactly what you ask: remove last two chars of a string:

```
s.substr(0, s.length-2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, the substring method `s.substr(0, s.length-2);` is actually quite a bit faster for removing the `px` (yes it isn't as clean looking, and if there is a space it will remain -- `"250px" -> "250"` vs `"250 px" -> "250 "`).

If you want to account for spaces (which you probably should) then using the `.trim()` function will actually slow down the `substr` test enough that the `parseInt` method actually becomes superior.

An added benefit of using `parseInt(s, 10)` is that you also get a type conversion and can immediately start to apply it to mathematical functions.

So in the end, it really depends on what you plan on doing with the result.

- If it is display only, then using the `substr` method **without** a trim would probably be your best bet.
- If you're just trying to see if the value without px is the same as another value `s.substr(0, s.length-2) == 0`, then using the `substr` method would be best, as `"250 " == 250` (even with the space) will result as `true`
- If you want to account for the possibility of a space, add it to another value, or to compute something with it, then you may want to consider going with the `parseInt` route.

http://jsperf.com/remove-px-from-coord

The tests on jspref account for a space. I also tried a `s.split('px')[0]` and `s.replace(/ *px/g, '')` function, both found to be slower.

Feel free to add additional test cases.

Answer (score 5):

Although parseInt() is a good option but still it is good to have many other solutions

```
var pixels = '245px';
Number(pixels.replace('px', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

`substr()` is [now a legacy feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr); use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead: (syntax is the same *in this case*)

```
str.substring(0, str.length-2);
```

Or, use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
str.slice(0, -2);
```

`slice()` looks much cleaner, IMO. Negative values count back from the end.

Comment: It makes for a less valueable function though, as it cannot be used for `rem` values.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp
In your case would be something like

```
string.substr(0, string.length - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:
`"245px".replace(/px/,'')*1`

since it's not surrounding the input.

Also, the `*1` is for casting it to int.