# Javascript convert string to integer

Tags: javascript

I am just dipping my toe into the confusing world of javascript, more out of necessity than desire and I have come across a problem of adding two integers.

> 1,700.00 + 500.00
>
> returns 1,700.00500.00

So after some research I see that 1,700.00 is being treated as a string and that I need to convert it.

The most relevant pages I read to resolve this were [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript) and [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). However when I use

`parseInt(string, radix)`

it returns 1. Am I using the wrong function or the an incorrect radix (being honest I can't get my head around how I decide which radix to use).

```
var a="1,700.00";
var b=500.00;
parseInt(a, 10);
```

Comment: `parseFloat` ? I don't think you can parse numbers `1,700.00`, which number do you expect as output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Basic Answer

The reason parseInt is not working is because of the comma.  You could remove the comma using a regex such as:

```
var num = '1,700.00';

num = num.replace(/\,/g,'');
```

This will return a string with a number in it.  Now you can parseInt.  If you do not choose a radix it will default to `10` which was the correct value to use here.

```
num = parseInt(num);
```

Do this for each of your string numbers before adding them and everything should work.

## More information

### How the replace works:

More information on replace at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
`/` - start  
`\,` - escaped comma  
`/` - end  
`g` - search globally
```

The global search will look for all matches (it would stop after the first match without this)
`''` replace the matched sections with an empty string, essentially deleting them.

### Regular Expressions

- A great tool to test regular expressions: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and more info about them at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- If you are looking for a good tutorial [here is one](http://regexone.com/).

### ParseInt and Rounding, parseFloat

parseInt always rounds to the nearest integer.  If you need decimal places there are a couple of tricks you can use. Here is my favorite:

```
2 places: `num = parseInt(num * 100) / 100;`
3 places: `num = parseInt(num * 1000) / 1000;`
```

For more information on parseInt look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

parseFloat could also be used if you do not want rounding.  I assumed you did as the title was convert to an integer.  A good example of this was written by @fr0zenFry below.  He pointed out that parseFloat also does not take a radix so it is always in base10.  For more info see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: That has worked, thankyou. Could you offer a bit of clarity to .replace(/\,/g,''); and why parseInt drops the .00 at the end of the string please?

Comment: +1 Thanks for noting my point in your answer.  I have updated my answer with alternate solution to yours(for decimal places).  Your approach may be better if one wants to make comparison after adding the numbers. I used `toFixed()` which converts the number back to string.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `replace()` to replace a `,` with `nothing` and then `parseFloat()` to get the number as float.  From the variables in OP,  it appears that there may be fractional numbers too, so,  `parseInt()` may not work well in such cases(digits after decimal will be stripped off).

Use regex inside `replace()` to get rid of each appearance of `,`.

```
var a = parseFloat('1,700.00'.replace(/,/g, '')); 
var b = parseFloat('500.00'.replace(/,/g, ''));
var sum = a+b;
```

This should give you correct result even if your number is fractional like `1,700.55`.

If I go by the title of your question,  you need an integer. For this you can use `parseInt(string, radix)`. It works without a `radix` but it is always a good idea to specify this because you never know how browsers may behave(for example,  see comment @Royi Namir). This function will round off the string to nearest integer value.

```
var a = parseInt('1,700.00'.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);   //radix 10 will return base10 value
var b = parseInt('500.00'.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
var sum = a+b;
```

Note that a radix is not required in `parseFloat()`,  it will always return a decimal/base10 value.  Also,  it will it will strip off any extra zeroes at the end after decimal point(ex: `17500.50` becomes `17500.5` and `17500.00` becomes `17500`).  If you need to get 2 decimal places always,  append another function `toFixed(decimal places)`.

```
var a = parseFloat('1,700.00'.replace(/,/g, '')); 
var b = parseFloat('500.00'.replace(/,/g, ''));   
var sum = (a+b).toFixed(2);    //change argument in toFixed() as you need
// 2200.00
```

Another alternative to this was given by @EpiphanyMachine which will need you to multiply and then later divide every value by `100`.  This may become a problem if you want to change decimal places in future,  you will have to change multiplication/division factor for every variable.  With `toFixed()`,  you just change the argument.  But remember that `toFixed()` changes the number back **to string** unlike @EpiphanyMachine solution.  So you will be your own judge.

Comment: do you know where the input comes from ? it might be input from a stupid user input or incorrect flow like `function getMeTheNumber(){return 010.toString();}; alert(parseFloat(getMeTheNumber().replace(/,/g, '')))` and your code will fail. why not specify radix ? you should build robust code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: again same answer from me: `parseFloat()` doesn't take radix.  It can work **only with** base10 (i.e., decimal values). It is applicable only for `parseInt()`. [#ref1](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=WMr2NEG88icC&lpg=PT483&ots=dVGOrIWpqQ&dq=javascript%20parsefloat%20radix&pg=PT483#v=onepage&q=javascript%20parsefloat%20radix&f=false), [#ref2](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/javascript/advanced.html), [#ref3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555649/second-argument-to-parsefloat-in-javascript)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Here is another nice [reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2012-Exploring-Javascript-s-parseInt-And-parseFloat-Functions.htm) you will love.

Comment: This doesn't seem to retain the .oo. How I can retain the numbers after the decimal place?

Comment: sorry this question answer my above question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435170/parse-float-with-two-decimal-places

Comment: @tony09uk:  updated my answer.  Also,  note that `toFixed()` will convert the number into string.  So,  comparison may not work on the result.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

`parseFloat(a.replace(/,/g, ''));`

it will work also on : `1,800,300.33`

Example :

`parseFloat('1,700,800.010'.replace(/,/g, ''))` //1700800.01

Comment: No it will not work on `1,800,300.33`.  With `parseInt('1,800,300.33'.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);`,  it becomes `1800300`.  See my answer,  `parseFloat()` should be used instead.

Comment: I guess, a radix is not required too.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr `parseInt('010')` in `ie8` returns 8. if you see a hole , dont try to block the hole. go around it.

Comment: Here we are talking about `parseFloat()`,  does this rule apply here too?  You are confusing it with `parseInt()`,  `parseFloat()` doesn't take second argument,  it takes only decimal.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr it will be required if the argument is number `parseFloat(010)` which is 8 ( ie8 , heck -010 _is_ 8). this is not the OP case since his input is string. but again whats the problem with specifying radix to be sure for all cases ?

Comment: No,  I'm just saying that `parseFloat()` doesn't take a radix. [#ref1](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=WMr2NEG88icC&lpg=PT483&ots=dVGOrIWpqQ&dq=javascript%20parsefloat%20radix&pg=PT483#v=onepage&q=javascript%20parsefloat%20radix&f=false), [#ref2](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/javascript/advanced.html), [#ref3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555649/second-argument-to-parsefloat-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't understand that comma. Remove it like this:

```
a.replace(',', '')
```

Once you've gotten rid of the comma, the string should be parsed with no problem.

Comment: this will replace only the first occurrence.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Good point, you're right. TBH I barely use Javascript. Go ahead and write a better answer and I will upvote it.