# Reading a value from a page and getting a wrong value back using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html page I have the div below and am doing some formatting

```
        <div class="diffhrs">
              <span class="lbl">Hours Left: </span>
              <span class="data">@String.Format("{0:0.0#}", Model.DiffHours)</span>
        </div>
```

When I look at the html rendered I get this. Note that it is 3.0

```
        <span class="data">3.0</span>
```

I have the line of code below in the click event of a button, same page. when I try to read the 
text in the div below I get 3.03 back.

```
        var ProductionHoursEntered = parseFloat($('div.diffhrs .data').text());
```

Do you know what is happening? where is the .03 coming from?

```js
var ProductionHoursEntered = parseFloat($('div.diffhrs .data').text());
console.log(ProductionHoursEntered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="diffhrs">
  <span class="lbl">Hours Left: </span>
  <span class="data">@String.Format("{0:0.0#}", Model.DiffHours)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you provided returns "3" - to answer your question better, we will need more context.

Comment: do you have an actual working of this page (for example, a jsfiddle)? are there lines above this ProductionHoursEntered that may be doctoring the number? Too many unknowns.

Comment: cannot reproduce. the issue would be related to whatever template engine you are using, which you didn't even tag. this question is not answerable since most programmers are not mind readers.

Comment: No I don't have a jsfiddle. It might be a little tough to put it on jsfiddle. I could check the lines above it.

Comment: are you sure that the value of span .data is 3.0?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple elements that match `'div.diffhrs .data'` and if you call `.text()` on them, jQuery will concatenate their contents. You basically get something like `"3.03.04.05.0"`; parsing this as float gives `3.03`.

The fix is to use

```
parseFloat($('div.diffhrs .data').eq(0).text());
```

Comment: Upvoted, but re: your fix . . . assuming that he wants the first one . . . otherwise, he should probably modify the jQuery selector to make the selection more specific.

Comment: This solution fixed it.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @talemyn Exactly. Assumed that to be self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a radix to your parseFloat method, to ensure you are returning a decimal value.

```
parseFloat('3.0',10);
```

Comment: Didn't downvoted your answer, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555649/second-argument-to-parsefloat-in-javascript

Comment: I did, because it doesn't solve the problem and therefore wasn't tested.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't tested? It does work. It just doesn't happen to solve the persons problem because that's not the cause of it, which I can't possibly know without more information of the source code.