# tablesorter, wont sort by date correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

Does the tablesorter behave differently if there is whitespace about?

I'm pretty new to tablesorter but I was asked quickly to add it to a customers site (specifically to allow them to sort by date published). As far as i am aware, the date (eg. 14 May 2012) is read as text, so I need to add a parser to change this to numeric in order for it to sort properly. (eg. 14052012)

This I have (currently using code written by the other developer - resides in the tablesorter.js).

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
id: 'dayMonthYear',
is: function(s) {
    return false;
},
format: function(s) {           

    var date = s.match(/^(\d{1,2})[ ](\w{3})[ ](\d{4})$/);
    var day = String(date[1]);
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }        

    var month = monthNames[date[2]];
    var year = date[3];
    var sortableDate = '' + year + month + day;
    return sortableDate;
},
type: 'numeric'  
});

var monthNames = {};
monthNames["Jan"] = "01";
monthNames["Feb"] = "02";
monthNames["Mar"] = "03";
monthNames["Apr"] = "04";
monthNames["May"] = "05";
monthNames["Jun"] = "06";
monthNames["Jul"] = "07";
monthNames["Aug"] = "08";
monthNames["Sep"] = "09";
monthNames["Oct"] = "10";
monthNames["Nov"] = "11";
monthNames["Dec"] = "12";
```

I also have this placed in the html page

```
$("table#searchresults").tablesorter ({
    headers: {
        0: {sorter:'dayMonthYear'}
    }
});
```

Although I've seen this code working, it doesnt seem to work for me. The month is still being read as text.

Any ideas? The only thing I can see different between the working demo and my site, is that the table has loads of whitespace kicking about, could this be an issue?

---

EDIT: Just found this, http://beausmith.com/blog/custom-date-sorting-for-jquery-tablesorter-plugin/, looks familiar to the above code. Hopefuly it helps...

Comment: This is because you parse the months as a string, pass them as int `monthNames["Jan"] = 01;`

Comment: Aw, I really thought you had it there. didnt seem to make a difference though. Doesn't actually sort at all now...Any other ideas?

Comment: You ought to move your "got it working" edit down to an answer. It's ok and even encouraged to answer your own question, and it works with the whole Q and A format better. And you get more reputation for an answer than a question!

Comment: Thanks MrBoJangles. Wasn't too sure how to do that. Will have a look and see though

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.. phew

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
id: 'dayMonthYear',
is: function(s) {
    return false;
},
format: function(s) {       

    s = $.trim(s.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));


    var date = s.match(/^(\d{1,2})[ ](\w{3})[ ](\d{4})$/);
    var day = String(date[1]);
    if (day.length == 1) { day = "0" + day;}        
    var month = monthNames[date[2]];
    var year = date[3];

    return sortableDate = '' + year + month + day;
},
type: 'numeric'  
});
var monthNames = {};
monthNames["Jan"] = "01";
monthNames["Feb"] = "02";
monthNames["Mar"] = "03";
monthNames["Apr"] = "04";
monthNames["May"] = "05";
monthNames["Jun"] = "06";
monthNames["Jul"] = "07";
monthNames["Aug"] = "08";
monthNames["Sep"] = "09";
monthNames["Oct"] = "10";
monthNames["Nov"] = "11";
monthNames["Dec"] = "12";
```

Comment: That worked. thanks..Date format for me was like 20th Feb 2014. I have to change var day = String(date[1]);  to  var day = parseInt(String(date[1]), 10);   Rest code was same.   after adding above parser.  add this code. 4 is the date column number in the table. $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({headers: {
                4: {sorter: 'dayMonthYear'}

            }
            })http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860244/how-to-delete-px-from-245px