# if statement command becomes invalid if page size over 1000

Tags: jquery

I have an if statement on my website which does commands when the page is under a certain size. there is one small problem. if the page size is over 1000 it automatically says the if statement is not true and goes to the else. my attempts are bellow

`if($("body").css("width") < 700 + "px")`

I have tried a plain < and I have also done <= I'm kinda new to jquery, all help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Use `if($( document ).width() < 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings. Strip off the trailing "px" from the left value ([How to delete "px" from 245px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860244/how-to-delete-px-from-245px)) and compare numbers.

```
if(parseInt($("body").css("width") , 10) < 700)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing it with jQuery is using `width` function instead of `css`.

Something like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1000) { 
    alert('Less than 1000'); 
} else { 
    alert('More than 1000'); 
}
```